# Does POSTGRES's query optimizer's statistical estimator compute a most common value list for an intermediate product of a multi-table join?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I am reading through Postgres' query optimizer's statistical estimator's code to understand how it works.

For reference, Postgres' query optimizer's statistical estimator estimates the size of the output of an operation (e.g. join, select) in a Postgres plan tree. This allows Postgres to choose between the different ways a query can be executed.

Postgres' statistical estimator uses cached statistics about the contents of each a relation's columns to help estimate output size. The two key saved data structures seem to be:

- A most common value (MCV) list: a list of each of the most common values stored in that column and the frequency that they appear in the column.
- A histogram of the data stored in that column.

For example, given the table:

```
X Y
1 A
1 B
1 C
2 A
2 D
3 B
```

The most common values list for Y would contain `{1:0.5, 2:0.333}`.

However, when Postgres completes the first join in a multi join operation like in the example below:

```
SELECT *
FROM A, B, C, D
WHERE A.ID = B.ID AND B.ID2 = C.ID2 AND C.ID3 = D.ID3
```

the resulting table does not have an MCV (or histogram) (since we've just created the table and we haven't `ANALYZE`d it! This will make it harder to estimate the output size/cost of the remaining joins.

*Does Postgres automatically generate/estimate the MCV (and histogram) for this table to help statistical estimation? If it does, how does it create this MCV?*

For reference, here's what I've looked at so far:

1. The documentation giving a high level overview of how Postgres statistical planner works: 
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/planner-stats-details.html
2. The code which carries out the majority of POSTGRES's statistical estimation:
   https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/selfuncs.c
3. The code which generates a relation's MCV:
   https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/statistics/mcv.c
4. Generic logic for clause selectivities:
   https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/optimizer/path/clausesel.c

A pointer to the right code file to look at would be much appreciated! Many thanks for your time. :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am interested in the internals of POSTGRES's planner/optimizer. I understand that one can augment an existing relation/view using CREATE STATISTICS - I am trying to work out whether POSTGRES automatically generates statistics for intermediate tables generated during query evaluation. :)
(These tables will not correspond to any table in the database since they will be destroyed after the query has finished executing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a join is called a *join relation* in PostgreSQL jargon, but that does not mean that it is a “materialized” table that is somehow comparable to a regular PostgreSQL table (which is called a *base relation*).

In particular, since the join relation does not physically exist, it cannot be `ANALYZE`d to collect statistics. Rather, the row count is estimated based on the size of the joined relations and the *selectivity* of the join conditions. This selectivity is a number between 0 (the condition excludes all rows) and 1 (the condition does not filter out anything).

The relevant code is in [`calc_joinrel_size_estimate`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/optimizer/path/costsize.c;h=b5a0033721f1742797fc4342b315d5a3f7c6bc81#l4546) in `src/backend/optimizer/path/costsize.c`, which you are invited to study.

The key points are:

- Join conditions that correspond to foreign keys are considered specially:

  If all columns in a foreign key are join conditions, then we know that the result of such a join must be as big as the referenced table, so the selectivity is `1 / referenced table size`.
- Other join conditions are estimated separately by guessing what percentage of rows will be eliminated by that condition.

  In the case of an left (or right) outer join, we know that the result size must be at least as big as the left (or right) side.
- Finally, the size of the cartesian join (the product of the relation sizes) is multiplied with all selectivities calculated above.

  Note that this treats all conditions as independent, which causes bad estimates if the conditions are correlated. But since PostgreSQL doesn't have cross-table statistics, it cannot do better.

Comment: Incredibly helpful, thank you! (I will work my way through the code and append a small summary on `clauselist_selectivity`'s operation, etc. to my q as a postscript for posterity.) Thank you for the advice & the pointer to the code!